# How to hide component with a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 application. And I want to hide a component if a condition is true.

The condition is this:

```
"status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"
```

So I tried like this:

**EcheqProcessComponent** template:

```
 <div *ngIf="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED">

    <app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"
      [isbtnDisabled]="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED"
      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
  </div>
```

**EcheqProcessComponent** ts file:

```
export class EcheqProcessComponent   implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(EcheqPageComponent, {static: false}) pageComponent: EcheqPageComponent;
  EcheqSubmissionStatus = EcheqSubmissionStatus;
  eCheqLoaded = false;
  eCheqError = false;
  currentEcheqSubmission: EcheqSubmission;
  currentEcheqDefinition: EcheqDefinition;
  currentEcheqPages: Array<EcheqPage>;
  currentEcheqPager: EcheqPager;
  currentEcheqPage: EcheqPage;
  currentEcheqPageIdx: number;
  currentEcheqId: string;
  currentEcheqPath = new Array<number>();
  sending = false;
  submitting = false;
```

But now always the navigation buttons are not visible. What not has to be.

and this is the ts of EcheqProgressNavComponent:

```
export class EcheqProgressNavComponent extends EcheqElementComponent implements OnInit {
  EcheqSubmissionStatus = EcheqSubmissionStatus;
  @Input() currentPage: number;
  @Input() totalPages: number;
  @Input() conditionals: { isFirst?: boolean; sending?: boolean };

  @Output() previous = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Output() next = new EventEmitter<void>();
  @Input() isbtnDisabled = true;
  @Input()  showComponent = false;



  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Yes, I also tried that of course:

```
 <div *ngIf="currentEcheqSubmission.status !== EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED">

    <app-echeq-progress-nav
      *ngIf="!submitting"
      [currentPage]="currentEcheqPageIdx + 1"
      [totalPages]="currentEcheqPath.length"
      (next)="next()"
      (previous)="prev()"

      [conditionals]="{
        isFirst: currentEcheqPager.isFirst,
        sending: sending
      }"

    ></app-echeq-progress-nav>
```

But then the component is still visible.

Comment: There's `currentEcheqSubmission` in your template, but no such variable in the TS.

Comment: Yes,it is updated

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div *ngIf="currentEcheqSubmission.status === EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED">
```

This *ngIf *shows* the div if the condition if true. If you want to hide it, you need to negate the condition.

```
    <div *ngIf="currentEcheqSubmission.status !== EcheqSubmissionStatus.EXPIRED">
```

Comment: On the other hand, if he just wants to hide it, he could use [hidden] attribute.